# From a list of tuples get the tuple with the largest difference between its elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Suppose I have a list of tuples like:

```
listTuples = [(0, 3), (5, 10), (2, 4)]
```

I want to get the index of the tuple with the largest difference between the tuple elements

```
3 - 0 = 3
10 - 5 = 5
4 - 2 = 2
```

So I want 1 as return.

Currently I am doing the following but perhaps there is a better way (faster, fewer lines of code) to do it.

```
listTuples = [(0, 3), (5, 10), (2, 4)] 

k = 0
e = 0

for j, i in enumerate(listTuples):
    diff = i[1] - i[0]
    if k < diff:
        k = diff
        e = j
    else:
        pass

print(e)
```

Comment: There are one-liner options as you can see from the answers, but regarding your own loop solution (which is arguably more readable), you can make it a little more concise by removing the `else: pass` which doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `index` method of the list object with `max` function. ie,

```
>>> listTuples = [(0, 3), (5, 10), (2, 4)]
>>> listTuples.index(max(listTuples, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0]))
1
```

Here `max(listTuples, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])` will return a tuple that has maximum difference and `index` method will find the index of this tuple from the original list.

ie, `listTuples.index((5, 10))`

Comment: Just to improvise the solution, so it can even work for negative values -             
   `print( listTuples.index( max(l, key=lambda x: abs(abs(x[1])-abs(x[0])) ) ) )` Feel free to share your thoughts on this :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `max()` with a custom key:

```
max(enumerate(listTuples), key = lambda x: x[1][1]-x[1][0])[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `max()` function:

```
x = [abs(j - i) for i, j in listTuples]
print(x.index(max(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the builtin `max` with a custom key function, like this:

```py
max(range(len(listTuples)), key=lambda i: listTuples[i][1] - listTuples[i][0])
```

It gives a value from `range(len(listTuples))`, based on the maximum value returned for each element from the `key` function.